# Access element from csr_matrix

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have created a Sparse matrix using the `Scipy` `dok_matrix` method as follows:

```
sparse_dtm = dok_matrix((num_documents, vocabulary_size), dtype=np.float32)
for doc_index, document in enumerate(data_list):
    document_counter = Counter(document)
    for word in set(document):
        sparse_dtm[doc_index, word_index[word]] = document_counter[word]
```

Where `data_list` is a list of lists with tokenized texts.

After having created `sparse_dtm`, I would like to retrieve all values for the first row.

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html)  I know that I can use the `.getrow()` method to get all elements from row `i`.

However, so far I am unable to retrieve the keys/values stored in the `csr_matrix`:

```
sparse_dtm.getrow(0).keys()
AttributeError: keys not found

sparse_dtm.getrow(0)[0]
<1x90140 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 576 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

`sparse_dtm` does contain the right information though:

```
print(sparse_dtm.getrow(0))
Output: (0, 21018)    6.0
        (0, 76741)    3.0
        (0, 14008)    1.0
        (0, 54143)    2.0
        (0, 11866)    1.0
        ...
```

How can I access elements from row `i` and retrieve its keys and values?

Comment: The `sparse` `dok` format is a subclass of `dict`, but `csr` is not.  It's data is stored in 3 arrays called `data`, `indices` and `indptr`.  `getrow` returns a new `csr` matrix with shape (1,n)`.  The `print` shows the indices and values, but is not an indication of how the matrix is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the values:

```
sparse_p_ij = dok_matrix((num_documents, vocabulary_size), dtype=np.float32)
row_zero = self.sparse_dtm.getrow(0).toarray()[0]
```

This provides all the values. To obtain the keys for each value, take the index of a non-zero value:

```
indices = row_zero.nonzero()[0]
```

Then feed these values to `index_to_word`, which I have created as follows:

```
word_to_index = dict()
index_to_word = dict()

for i, word in enumerate(vocabulary):
    word_to_index[word] = i
    index_to_word[i] = word
```

Where `vocabulary` is a set of all the words in the corpus.